# How to trigger the button by pressing enter key on a input textbox in the cshtml page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

Textbox field:

```
   <input id="LastName" type="text" filtercolumn="LastName" class="filterCtrl" style="width:135px; height:15px"/>
```

Want to trigger the following button when pressing enter key on the above text box:

```
<input type="button" class="button w100" onclick="javascript:btnAdvanceSearchClick();" value="Search" />
```

Javascript function for ajax requesting the grid when button is clicked:

```
function btnAdvanceSearchClick() {
        _loadData = true;
        var $grid = $('#AdvanceSearchGrid').data('tGrid'); 
        $grid.ajaxRequest();
        $('div#divSearchGrid').show();
}
```

My Search ActionControl method is called from the following code:

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Web.Mvc.Models.Search.SearchModel>()
    .Name("AdvanceSearchGrid")
    .DataBinding(db => db.Ajax()
        .Select("SearchUserByFilter", "Search", new { _loadData, _filter }).Enabled(true)
                )
```

How to hit the button when the user clicked enterkey in the textbox. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

here is a simple mark up i wrote based on what you are trying to achieve

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="LastName" type="text" />
    <input id="searchButton" type="button" onclick="javascript: btnAdvanceSearchClick();" value="Search" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#LastName").keypress(function (event) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    $("#searchButton").click();
                }
            });
        });

        function btnAdvanceSearchClick() {
            alert("search invoked. Query : " + $("#LastName").val());
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am attaching a keypress event to the textbox. When the keypress event happens - i check if it is Enter key press. If yes i just call the click() method on the button.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a function to `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` event and check if the last key pressed is an enter (new line character). If it is then execute the button click.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function triggerButton() {
            var input = $("#LastName");
            var lastKey = input.val().substr(input.val().length-1);
            if (lastKey == '\n') {
                 $("#mybutton").click();
            }
        }

        function onClick() {
            $("#p1").html('the button was clicked!');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="LastName" type="text" filtercolumn="LastName" onkeyup="triggerButton()" class="filterCtrl" style="width:135px; height:15px"></textarea>
    <button id='mybutton' onclick='onClick()'>Button</button>
    <p id='p1'></p>
</body>
```

Comment: "input" is undefined error message is displayed. Also I need for when clicking enter key and not in the keyup. Thanks

Comment: I fixed the input error. Keyup is triggered any time a key is pressed. If the key that was pressed was an enter key then it will run the button.click event, so that should do exactly what you want it to. However I don't think input will allow enter's so you would have to switch it to `<textarea></textarea>`